# How to allow JavaScript to change `window.status` in Chromium?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, statusbar, chromium

Yeah, I know the security implications (which are rather negligible anyway due widely used workaround), but I'd still like to have this restriction lifted. So far I've checked out [command line flags](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but had no luck finding one which changes this behavior. Please advise. FWIW, I'm using last known good development version (65.0.3325.0).